# Как использовать файл внутри собранной программы Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, pyinstaller

Как сделать, чтобы программа могла считывать, например, конфиги, которые будут находиться внутри самого исполняемого exe файла. Например, я собираю проект через pyinstaller и мне надо, чтобы программа искала путь к файлам не в каталоге, где она находится, а внутри себя. Как это можно реализовать? Например, как в Java `getClass().getResource(file)`

Comment: Создайте конфигурационный файл и добавьте его через опцию add_data PyInstaller в исполняемый файл

Comment: Вам не помог ни один из ответов на ваш предыдущий вопрос или вы просто игнорируете [правила ресурса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) и не отмечаете решения?

Comment: я имею в виду как указать программе искать файл именно там

Comment: Походу никак у меня не получилось :(

Comment: Вроде как это невозможно

Comment: @DGDays, получить доступ к файлу можно (при запуске все содержимое exe распаковывается во временную папку, соответственно ко всем запакованным файлам можно получить доступ), но только измененных конфиг не будет запакован обратно в exe, поэтому нет смысла упаковывать в exe конфиги.

Comment: Подскажи как это сделать? софтина каждый раз создает новую временную папку :(

Answer (score 0):

При запуске все содержимое exe распаковывается во временную директорию, соответственно ко всем запакованным файлам можно получить доступ. Чтобы это сделать, нужно получить путь к текущему модулю, из него получить директорию, в которой он лежит, а к ней уже добавить имя файла, который нужно прочитать. Для примера, есть основной модуль и рядом с ним упакован файл file.txt:

```
import sys
from os import path

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Получаем директорию, в которой лежит данный модуль
    current_module_directory = path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
    # или current_module_directory = path.dirname(__file__)
    # Добавляем имя файла к пути
    file_path = path.join(current_module_directory, 'file.txt')
    # Читаем файл по полученному пути
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        print(file.read())
```

Однако изменяемые конфигурационные файлы так хранить не получится: измененные файлы не упаковываются потом обратно в exe, и при следующем запуске будет прочитан исходный конфиг, тот что был упакован изначально.